# 16 digit timestamp to Javascript date format

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I am getting a 16-digit Timestamp from the server.
For example :  I got "1485157072432000" from the server and when I use the time stamp converter it is showing as **Wed Oct 03 49032 04:43:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

However,I am getting the exact time when I remove the last 3-digits from the 16-digit number. But I'm getting 16 digit Timestamp from server. What is the way to get exact time from 16-digit Timestamp??

Comment: Can you show us how are you creating date? Coz its working fine

Comment: `new Date(1485239482274)` _Tue Jan 24 2017 06:31:22 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)_

Comment: @BenG OP is from India, hence `12:01:22`. And yes there is no issue with timestamp. I guess ` time stamp converte` is messing something.

Comment: Did you get a look at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219182/1133284

It's a question for C# language, but the concept is the same!

Comment: @SaiHanuman are you using Node.JS to develop your web application?

Comment: @Brutus we are getting the data from Java RESTful Web services.

Comment: @SaiHanuman that was clear, but what is the environment in which you are developing? Is it a pure HTML/JavaScript project or are you using something like Node.JS?

There is also something that is not quite clear to me: what is the problem about the workaround you tried (removing the last 3 digits)? The data you are receiving is a TimeStamp in microseconds, when you remove the last 3 digits you get a TimeStamp in milliseconds. Isn't it not enough for you? Do you really need the microseconds precision?

Comment: @Brutus we are using Java as back-end and yes we need microseconds also. So is there any solution for getting microseconds by using 16-digit(without removing last 3-digits)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the microseconds precision I guess that the only solution is to use a custom object where you store all the information you need.

I would suggest you to use something like [this utility](https://github.com/kamicane/microseconds) developed by the GitHub user **kamikane**.

In particular you need the *parse* function that he developed:

```
function parse(nano) {

    var ms = nano / 1000;
    var ss = ms / 1000;
    var mm = ss / 60;
    var hh = mm / 60;
    var dd = hh / 24;

    var microseconds = Math.round((ms % 1) * 1000);
    var milliseconds = Math.floor(ms % 1000);
    var seconds = Math.floor(ss % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(mm % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(hh % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(dd);

    return { microseconds: microseconds, milliseconds: milliseconds, seconds: seconds, minutes: minutes, hours: hours, days: days, toString: toString };
};
```

Example usage:

```
parse(1485157072432010);

{ microseconds: 10, milliseconds: 432, seconds: 52, minutes: 37, hours: 7, days: 17189 }
```